# Text matching from one list to another

Tags: r

I want to search for a value in one column 1 of a list, and return all of the values in column 2.
where numb_name is the 'dictionary' showing the number (column 1) to name (column 2) list

I have used this, successfully:

```
numb_name[numb_name[,1]=="688560462",2]
```

but now, instead of searching by numbers individually, I want to search for a list of, say 200 numbers, and return all of their names- but I'm not sure how to progressively search through each item in, e.g., the first column of a separate list/matrix.

Comment: try `numb_name[numb_name[,1] %in% dictionary,2]`